# Check if JS file is included

Tags: selenium

How can I check if a js file is included in my web page?  I had a look of a lot of Selenium Documentations, but i did not find what i want.

Thanks a lot for you reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question (with the JUnit 3 format):

```
verifyTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("//script[@type='text/javascript'][contains(@src,'my.js')]"));
```